# Where can I publish a paper about how to write mathematical papers?

Tags: soft-question, journals, mathematical-writing, advice

I am thinking about writing a paper: "How (not) to write a mathematical paper." I want to share my thoughts and experience about good and bad habits, and common mistakes. While it will be a subjective point of view and some of the readers may not agree with my ideas, I think it still could be a useful source. My question is where can I publish such a paper? Is there any journal that would publish such work?

Comment: I know that the Notices of the AMS has advice columns of various sorts. But this is just a guess.

Comment: Already on arXiv does this take place under "General Mathematics"?

Comment: There's, by the way, a talk by J-P. Serre in Harvard around 2010 "How to write mathematics badly" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECQyFzzBHlo&ab_channel=ChristophPegel

Comment: _How to Write Mathematics_ by P. Halmos appeared in [L’Enseignement mathématique 16 (1970), 123-152]. What about submitting your work to the journal?

Comment: Also Krantz, A primer of Mathematical Writing. I guess the market for article length is different. Certainly I'd expect occasional pieces intended for graduate students....  searched https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/02/how_to_write_mathematics_badly.html   posted by John Baez.   Videos  Wildberger https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8LIJVmPj6g   and full length by Serre https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECQyFzzBHlo

Comment: Such a paper seems very likely appropriate for the Notices of the AMS, as Donu Arapura suggests.

Comment: Possibly even more appropriate than Notices of the AMS is [*The Mathematical Intelligencer*](https://link.springer.com/journal/283).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I think that *The Mathematical Intelligencer* would be a more appropriate venue for an unconventional essay on this topic; e.g., one that is humorous or tongue-in-cheek, or that offers unorthodox or controversial advice. But a conventional essay seems more suitable for the *Notices*, which in recent years has increased its emphasis on career advice.

Comment: @Timothy Chow: "*unconventional essay* $\ldots$ *humorous or tongue-in-cheek* $\ldots$ *unorthodox or controversial advice*" -- Now that I think about it, most of the articles I have from MI, downloaded (when I've had access) or photocopied during the past several decades, are of this nature (e.g. Koblitz's 1981 article *Mathematics as propaganda* and Montaño's 2012 article *Ugly mathematics*). I suppose this could be a self-selection effect on my part, but I suspect what you say is true more generally for MI articles.

Comment: St. Petersburg Mathematical Journal has a section called "Easy Reading for a Professional".

Comment: Just put it on the web using arXiv or your own webpage and send it to a few people whose opinions you consider worthwhile before submitting it to any journal. If this advice on writing papers is not on your list of things (not) to do, consider adding it or arguing against it :-)

Comment: @fedja Certainly my first and perhaps the  last choice would be arXiv. I would like to see opinion of others and I would use it to modify my paper. In fact, before writing anything, I would like to start a discussion on MathOverflow.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I agree with you, many first time publishers will attempt to get something accepted on arXiv and would likely appreciate some advice on how to get the basic precondition, namely the writing style, right. If the paper on writing papers were accompnied with some tex templates then that would be really great

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you write anything, including a paper on "How (not) to write a mathematical paper," it is wise to ask yourself **who is my intended audience?** That influences the choice of where to publish and of course how to frame your argument.

If your audience is professional mathematicians seeking actual advice, then Notices of the AMS [has already been suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460452/where-can-i-publish-a-paper-about-how-to-write-mathematical-papers#comment1194139_460452). On their [Information for Authors page](https://www.ams.org/publications/notices/noticesauthors), they write:

> **Topics**. Notices seeks exceptional articles that report on major new developments in mathematics or that describe great mathematicians or episodes from mathematics history that have connections to current research in the field. We also welcome articles discussing aspects of the mathematics profession, such as grant programs, the job market, professional opportunities for mathematicians, publishing, electronic communications, and mathematics education, at all levels. In addition, we publish reviews of books. The Notices does not publish articles which are offensive or inflammatory.

For something unconventional, controversial, or humorous, Math Intelligencer has been suggested. Their [aims and scope](https://link.springer.com/journal/283/aims-and-scope) says:

> The Mathematical Intelligencer publishes articles about mathematics, about mathematicians, and about the history and culture of mathematics. Written in an engaging, informal style, our pages inform and entertain a broad audience of mathematicians and the wider intellectual community. We welcome expository articles on all kinds of mathematics, and articles that portray the diversity of mathematical communities and mathematical thought, emergent mathematical communities around the world, new interdisciplinary trends, and relations between mathematics and other areas of culture. Humor is welcome, as are puzzles, poetry, fiction, and art.

If your audience is graduate students, then the [Graduate Journal of Mathematics](https://gradmath.org/) could be a good option.

If your goal is to influence how we teach mathematical writing, or supervising undergraduates in their first exposure to research (e.g., at an REU), then [PRIMUS might be a good choice](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?show=aimsScope&journalCode=upri20). I published a paper there [about how to teach statistics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08858). Another option would be Involve. A colleague [published a paper there](http://personal.denison.edu/%7Eludwigl/2014involvearticle.pdf) about how to teach students how to give good talks, and how to write.

If your goal is to comment on issues with mathematical writing on an even larger scale, you might consider the Journal of Humanistic Mathematics. [Their aims and scope page](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/aimsandscope.html) says:

> The Journal of Humanistic Mathematics provides an open forum for both academic and informal discussions on the various threads of mathematical inquiry. The focus of submitted papers should be on the aesthetic, cultural, historical, literary, pedagogical, philosophical, psychological, and sociological aspects of doing, learning, and teaching mathematics. Authors should keep in mind that the Journal publishes work that appeals to a general mathematical audience. This includes people who are seriously interested in mathematics, but may come from a variety of backgrounds both within and beyond academia.

I published two papers there ([The User's Guide Project: Giving Experiential Context to Research Papers](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1291&context=jhm), and [The User's Guide Project: Looking Back and Looking Forward](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/288168943.pdf)) that were related to the topic of how math papers are written and consequences of our ways of doing things, from the point of view of welcoming and encouraging junior researchers.

As others have pointed out, one could also just host the note on your webpage or on arXiv, but in general I think it's a service to actually get such things published. Doing so provides a canonical reference, staying power (webpages don't last forever), and authority to your argument. Also, I've found that the process of getting such essays through peer review really does improve my writing and the framing of the argument I'm trying to make. More focus on quality writing is always welcome, and is definitely needed (as I'm sure you know). I encourage you to write the paper you have in mind, and go through the steps of getting it published!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I will stick to arXiv at least for a while. Regarding Notices, I know it would be by far the best choice, but publishing there might be perceived as immodest since it will be my own thoughts and others might disagree with me.

Comment: I would not let concerns of modesty hold you back, if you think your article has value for the readership. Certainly plenty of others have published in notices and ignored the potential criticism of immodesty. Wasn't there a big issue a few years ago about diversity statements and loyalty oaths, with strong opinions published in the Notices? I might be misremembering. Anyway, for sure any opinion piece has opinions, and this is what they are looking for (well-argued, of course)!

Comment: Regarding modesty, if you send it to the Notices, the worst they'll do is say no. Let the editors there decide if you are being overly immodest.